# React test not behaving the same as browser (React-testing-library)

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library

I have a component that is using another child input component. The behavior is working well in the browser but during the test, the code is not behaving in the same way and I want to know why.

in FilterItems.js

```
import { useState } from "react";
import SearchBar from "./Searchbar";

export default function FilterItems() {
  const [items, setItems] = useState([]);

  const handleChange = () => {
    console.log("Handle Change triggered");
    setItems(["hello", "hello world", "hello there"]);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <SearchBar defaultValue={""} handleChange={handleChange} />

      {items.length ? (
        <ul data-testid="items">
          {items.map((el, index) => (
            <li key={index}>{el}</li>
          ))}
        </ul>
      ) : null}
    </div>
  );
}
```

in SearchBar.js

```
import React, { useEffect, useState, useRef } from "react";

const DebounceQuery = (value, delay) => {
  const [debouncedValue, setDebouncedValue] = useState(value);

  useEffect(() => {
    const handler = setTimeout(() => {
      setDebouncedValue(value);
    }, delay);

    return () => {
      clearTimeout(handler);
    };
  }, [value, delay]);

  return debouncedValue;
};

const SearchBar = ({ defaultValue = "", handleChange = () => {} }) => {
  const [query, setQuery] = useState(defaultValue);
  const debouncedQuery = DebounceQuery(query, 500);
  const ref = useRef(true);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (ref.current) {
      ref.current = false;
      return;
    }

    if (debouncedQuery !== "") handleChange();
  }, [debouncedQuery]);

  useEffect(() => {
    setQuery(defaultValue);
  }, [defaultValue]);

  return (
    <input
      placeholder="search"
      onChange={(e) => {
        console.log("setQuery triggered");
        setQuery(e.target.value);
      }}
      value={query}
    />
  );
};

export default SearchBar;
```

in FilterItems.test.js

```
import React from "react";

import { render, fireEvent } from "@testing-library/react";
import FilterItems from "./FilterItems";

describe("Tests FilterItems", () => {
  it("Tests that items appear after search is filled", () => {
    const { getByPlaceholderText, getByTestId } = render(<FilterItems />);

    const searchInput = getByPlaceholderText("search");
    fireEvent.change(searchInput, { target: { value: "hello" } });
    const items = getByTestId("items");
    expect(items).toBeInTheDocument();
  });
});
```

As you can see in the code, I have two console.log statements. When running the tests only one gets triggered (one in child Searchbar component) but the statement in the parent FilterItems component doesn't get triggered.

I do not understand why this is happening? and how do I make sure my test is behaving like the browser?

You can find the sandbox here:

[Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/condescending-cerf-k35k0n?file=%2Fsrc%2FSearchbar.js&selection=%5B%7B%22endColumn%22%3A43%2C%22endLineNumber%22%3A42%2C%22startColumn%22%3A43%2C%22startLineNumber%22%3A42%7D%5D)

Comment: You need to use `act` and stop silencing the lint warning about exhaustive deps.

Comment: @morganney I stopped silencing the lint warning and added act, now even my searchbar is undetectable, not sure how I have to use act...I am pretty new to this :/

Comment: `act(() => {
      const { getByTestId } = render(<FilterItems />);

      const searchInput = getByTestId("searchbar");
      fireEvent.change(searchInput, { target: { value: "hello" } });
      const items = getByTestId("items");
      expect(items).toBeInTheDocument();
    });`

Comment: @Donatello You should actually fix the ESLint warning about exhaustive dependencies, not just "stop silencing" it. This warning is there for a reason, namely that your code is most likely broken and won't behave properly.

Answer (score 0):

The test is most likely not working as you are not waiting for the asynchronous events to complete in the component being tested i.e. the change in the search value and the query.

Try changing your test to:

```
import React from "react";
import { render, fireEvent } from "@testing-library/react";
import FilterItems from "./FilterItems";

describe("Tests FilterItems", () => {
  it("Tests that items appear after search is filled", async () => {
    const { getByPlaceholderText, getByTestId } = render(<FilterItems />);

    const searchInput = getByPlaceholderText("search");
    await fireEvent.change(searchInput, { target: { value: "hello" } });
    const items = await findByTestId("items");
    expect(items).toBeInTheDocument();
  });
});
```

This test will now wait for the effects to complete before asserting values. You will probably also need to import `findByTestId`.